# Java: how to group list elements by property

Tags: java

Here's the Scenario:

I have a list of Segment objects: List segments that I needed to group by set.

** Segments Data**

```
[CODE]: 9X-594 (D/ET) - [SET]: 1
[CODE]: 9X-600 (D/ET) - [SET]: 2
[CODE]: 9X-602 (D/ET) - [SET]: 3
[CODE]: 9X-596 (D/ET) - [SET]: 4

[CODE]: 9X-970 (S/ET) - [SET]: 5
[CODE]: 9X-579 (E/ET)

[CODE]: 9X-974 (S/ET) - [SET]: 6
[CODE]: 9X-589 (E/ET)
[CODE]: 9X-599 (E/ET)

[CODE]: 9X-964 (S/ET) - [SET]: 7
[CODE]: 9X-581 (E/ET)
```

I needed to group these data into this format:

```
List<CodeSample> samples = new ArrayList<CodeSample>();
```

Where CodeSample is a class that contains list of Segment.

```
public class CodeSample {

    private int set;
    private List<Segment> segments;

    //getters/setters here
    ...
}
```

I needed to group the segments by set, something like:

```
samples = [
    { set: 1, [{code: "9x-594 (D/ET)"}]},
    { set: 2, [{code: "9x-600 (D/ET)"}]},
    { set: 3, [{code: "9x-602 (D/ET)"}]},
    { set: 4, [{code: "9x-596 (D/ET)"}]},
    { set: 5, [{code: "9x-970 (D/ET)"}, {code: "9x-579 (D/ET)"}]},
    { set: 6, [{code: "9x-974 (D/ET)"}, {code: "9x-589 (D/ET)"}, {code: "9x-599 (D/ET)"}]},
    { set: 7, [{code: "9x-964 (D/ET)"}, {code: "9x-581 (D/ET)"}]}
]
```

I needed to create a list of samples containing the list of segments (grouped).

What is the best approach for this scenario?

Comment: Are you using Java 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<CodeSample> result = 
    segments.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Segment::getSet))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(entry -> new CodeSample(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks man and a lot shorter code! Other than shorter code using Java 8 Streams, is it faster than coding this in java 7?

Comment: No, you can probably write Java 7 code that is as, or more efficient. But it will be longer, more error-prone, harder to read and understand.

Comment: Thanks a lot JB :)